# How to find the innermost fail pattern from this logging output

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this logging output. I want to match the `path/to/*.command`of all failed commands.In this case it's third and  forth commands.

> ```
>     Starting.. path/to/first.command
>       Some Text..
>     Done
>
>     Starting.. other/path/to/second.command
>       Some Other Text..
>     Done
>
>     Starting.. other/path/to/third.command
>       Some Text..
>     Fail
>
>     Starting.. other/path/to/forth.command
>       Some Other Text..
>     Fail
> ```

This is what I came up with `Starting.. (.+\.command)[\s\S]+?Fail`

But it's not good enough. The reluctant quantifier *doesn't match the inner most match third.command* . But instead it matches enclosing first.command (Which is correct, in terms of the regex, but undesired)

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/fl3eaz/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s\S]+` will greedily match any sequence of characters, including newlines, but you only want to search to the point where the `Fail` or `Done` is encountered. Because the `Some Text` lines are always exactly one line long, take advantage of that by (after the command) matching a *single* `[\s\S]` (newline), followed by a line of characters, followed by another `[\s\S]+` (newline), followed by `Fail`.

```js
const input = `
    Starting.. path/to/first.command
      Some Text..
    Done

    Starting.. other/path/to/second.command
      Some Other Text..
    Done

    Starting.. other/path/to/third.command
      Some Text..
    Fail

    Starting.. other/path/to/forth.command
      Some Other Text..
    Fail
    `;
const re = /Starting\.\. (.+\.command)[\s\S].+[\s\S] +Fail/g;
let match;
while (match = re.exec(input)) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

It's simpler if you use (newer, less supported) lookbehind:

```js
const input = `
    Starting.. path/to/first.command
      Some Text..
    Done

    Starting.. other/path/to/second.command
      Some Other Text..
    Done

    Starting.. other/path/to/third.command
      Some Text..
    Fail

    Starting.. other/path/to/forth.command
      Some Other Text..
    Fail
    `;
const re = /(?<=Starting\.\. +).+\.command(?=[\s\S].+[\s\S] +Fail)/g;
console.log(input.match(re));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But doesn't \s\S account for all characters? Not just newlines and spaces?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Looking at your regex101, the problem was that it was matching more than one `Starting` to `Done` / `Fail` chunk at a time, which is why it works to use `[\s\S]` to match a single newline character only when necessary (rather than `[\s\S]+` to match *any sequence*)

Comment: Yeah. Figured out as much. Thanks :)